# PHP Password Attempts Blocking

Tags: php

I am wondering the best way to handle blocking computers after the users commit 5 wrong login attempts.

I was thinking to have it does by IP but then I started thinking what about if users were coming through a gateway and shared a common IP. I wouldn't want to potentially block legimate users because someone else on the same network is entering incorrect data.

Cookies are another option but users can clear them from the browser so i think they would be very ineffective.

Can anyone else give me anymore ideas on this please?

Thanks Mic

Comment: Perhaps just slow them down (exponentially?): e.g. 1 second wait for first try, 2 seconds for second try, 4 seconds for third try, 8 for fourth, 16 for fifth, 32 for sixth, 64 for seventh, etc.

Comment: Don't forget to reset the above to 0 on success. Otherwise your forgetful users will end up with huge waits on failure. Which is hilarious, but not user friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do something like:

If user commit 5 wrong login attempts:

- Block the users login for 15 [xxx] minutes (so if he try also if the password is correct it won't work)
- Add a captcha control, so others users can login without problem...

I'll do that by IP and Username...

Simply save in the database the timestamp of the last wrong attempt followed by the incremental value of wrong attemps.

Then if he tries to login before a determinated time (let's assume 15 mins) from last wrong attempt and

- the incremental value is lower than the max login attempt, simply update the incremental value+1 and timestamp with the new timestamp
- the incremental value is equal (or higher) you block the login attempt and increment the timestamp with new timestap

Comment: Here's a problem with this method. If I try to connect to  account 5 time to  _your_ account and failed,  _you_ can't connect to your account.

Comment: @Luc but anyway that's the only reliable method. Though with good passwords the timeout could be really small, like a few seconds.

Comment: i think this method is the best solution i can do with the time constraints for my project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PEAR::HTTP_FloodControl](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_FloodControl)

```
<?php
if ($login_not_successful) {
require_once 'HTTP/FloodControl.php';
try {
    $ip = HTTP_FloodControl::getUserIP();
} catch (HTTP_FloodControl_Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}
try {
    $fc =& new HTTP_FloodControl();
    $fc->setContainer('File', '/home/user1/logs');
    $limits = array (
        10   => 10,  // maximum 10 requests in 10 seconds
        60   => 30,  // maximum 30 requests in 60 seconds
        300  => 50,  // maximum 50 requests in 300 seconds
        3600 => 200  // maximum 200 requests in 3600 seconds
    );
    if (!$fc->check($limits, $ip)) {
        die('Too many requests. Please try later.');
    }
} catch (HTTP_FloodControl_Exception $e) {
    die($e);
}
}
// Your login form
?>
```

Comment: as it was already pointed out, an IP based solution is weac and won't protect anything

Comment: i would prefer to use a non PEAR solution but that for the input. I will take a look at this for possible future use